# Hamiltonians and Hilbert spaces in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, hilbert-space, hamiltonian

Suppose we start from a theory with a given $\mathcal{L}$ and correspondigly a Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$. Now a state of this $\mathcal{H}$ is (say) $|p,q,r>$. Now suppose that we do a set of allowed transformations in the $\mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}_1+\mathcal{L}_2+\mathcal{L}_3$ leading also to $\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_1+\mathcal{H}_2+\mathcal{H}_3$. In this case, I think that the the state vector completely decomposes $|p,q,r> \rightarrow |p>|q>|r>$. Is this true? What is the formal argument behind this?

Comment: Sounds like OP is considering factorization into various non-interacting sectors.

Comment: Yeah but how does this answer the question above?

Comment: What do you mean "a state of the Hamiltonian"? Did your second $\mathcal{H}$ mean the Hilbert space? Do you have some rule for how you are splitting $\mathcal{L}$ into terms? How does this relate to your original state $|p, q, r\rangle$?